# DI and $app error in phalcon

Tags: php, dependency-injection, phalcon

I use micro app Phalcon, I created a DI to my class named utility. When I get the shared utility through $app->utility an error occurred.

```
$di->setShared('utility',function(){
    return new utility();
});
$app->get("213",function(){});
$app->utility;
```

error:
Access to undefined property utility in ($app)

But if I change the code to

```
$di->setShared('utility',function(){
    return new utility();
});
$app->utility;
$app->get("213",function(){});
```

It works fine.
WHY?

PHP = 5.6.17

Phalcon = 2.7 or 2.8 or 2.9

windows 10 + nginx

THANKS!

Comment: Phalcon = 2.0.7 or 2.0.8 or 2.0.9

Comment: Instance of what is `$app` and what does `$app->get("213",function(){})` thing? Question is incomplete, please provide us with minimalistic, working example to doplicate your problem.

Comment: Maybe $di->get('utility'), or $di->getUtility?   https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/di.html#resolving-services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$app is an instance of Macro.
    $app = Macro($di);
post $di as a param to Macro and it's work fine.